# Regex - Strings with Odd/Even characters

Tags: regex

on my homework assignment I have an alphabet a, b, and c.

I have two questions that I cannot figure out.

1) strings with an odd amount of characters.

2) strings with an even amount of characters.

How can I track even/odd strings in regex? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By *track*, do you mean *match*?

Comment: yes, sorry for the misinterpretation on my part.

Comment: I’ll give you a hint for strings with an even amount of characters.  You have a fixed alphabet, and the only two-character combinations are: `aa`, `ab`, `ac`, `ba`, etc.  If the string matches one or more of those combinations, then it has an even amount of characters.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with the following simple regular expressions:

Even-character strings:

```
^(..)*$
```

This matches any two characters zero or more times.

#### [Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/SOTApX/2)

Odd-character strings:

```
^.(..)*$
```

This uses the same expression as the first but with an extra character at the beginning to add one to the total string length.

#### [Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/Qjp70V/1)

Comment: The first regex does not match an empty string but 0 is an even number too.

Comment: @blhsing You're right. Mathematics isn't my strong suit so I forgot 0 is considered even. Made the correction.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with even _numbers_, but rather an even number of _characters_.  The number `0` should not match the first regex.  Also, the OP stated that he was matching letters, not every character.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen _Characters_ in regular expressions usually consist of letters _and_ numbers. I wouldn't assume anything.

Answer (score 3):

A string with an even number of characters can be phrased as a pair of characters, occurring zero or more times:

```
^(?:[a-z]{2})*$
```

### Demo

This would match empty string, 2 characters, 4 characters, etc.

For an odd string, we can slightly modify the above pattern to this:

```
^(?:[a-z]{2})*[a-z]$
```

### Demo

This matches zero or more pairs of characters (whose count is _even), followed by a single character, which would make the total count *odd*.